# How to extend XML-RPC such that a single request generates multiple responses?

Tags: client-server, rpc, xml-rpc, json-rpc

I have an existing application which acts as an XML-RPC server.
The clients of that server are other programs which run on the same computer.

The clients form connections to the server, invoke commands using XML-RPC, and await responses. The details of the connection and transport protocol are not relevant for this discussion.

The set of available commands constitutes a versioned API between the server and his clients.
I am at liberty to change any code on the server, and also to change library code shared between the clients which handles the details of XML-RPC.

I can therefore introduce an incompatibility with the XML-RPC spec' in my implementation - I control the relevant code in both server and client; nothing touches the internet.

I wish to evolve the API such that a subset of commands invoked by the client(s) cause **two** separate responses to be generated, each of which is correlated to the original request.

```
+--------+              +--------+         
|        |              |        |         
| Client |              | Server |         
|        |              |        |         
+---+----+              +---+----+         
    |                       |              
    |        request        |              
    +--------------------> +-+             
    |                      |-|             
    |                      |-|             
    |     initial response |-|             
    | <- - - - - - - - - - |-|             
    |                      |-|             
    |                      |-|             
    |    ultimate response |-|             
    | <- - - - - - - - - - +-+                     
    |                       |              
    +                       +
```

The client will have distinct states (and therefore will be performing different tasks) whilst awaiting the initial response, and the ultimate response.

I already have the ability to send an unsolicited "event" from the server to the client, so I *could* solve this problem by generating an event representing the initial response, then use the existing XML-RPC mechanism to deliver the ultimate response.  This is very unsatisfactory though; for the sanity of the client code the two responses need to be correlated with (i.e they should share an id with) the original request.

I am struggling to imagine a clean way of solving this problem.

- Is there some metaphor I am missing, which would help form a design?
- Is there an existing RPC system, or some extension to XML-RPC / JSON-RPC which allows a single request to beget multiple responses in this fashion?
- Has anyone dealt with a similar problem - can they provide some insights?

Note that the initial and ultimate responses must be separate XML stanzas.
Specifically, it must be possible for the server to deliver unsolicited XML stanzas (which do not pertain to the request) to the client whilst he awaits the ultimate response.

Comment: There are two discussions of similar problems with JSON-RPC2: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/json-rpc/EWnUwcTmOjY/x-1_beeIJPoJ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/json-rpc/5PcrYSfzavA/cLW5buMC48EJ